# How do I see real-time downloads of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect seem to be updating sales reports every 24 hours, is there a tool or way to see real-time app download figures for iOS developers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see real-time app-sales figures.

Comment: And yes, that sucks. >:(

Comment: Unless your app is downloaded 10 000 times per day, I think you don't need to see real time sales.